# Group Javascript objects in array with same key and adding new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, javascript-objects

I am trying to change the data structure of an array of objects in JS. I have an array of objects that contain the same keys that I would like to merge to one for example `route`. And then would like to add `query` and `time` in a new array. Example below:

How do I change this data structure:

```
const array = [
    {
        query: "query1",
        route: "home",
        time: 1234
    },
    {
        query: "query2",
        route: "dashboard",
        time: 4324
    },
    {
        query: "query3",
        route: "home",
        time: 1200
    },
    {
        query: "query4",
        route: "admin",
        time: 3333
    },
    {
        query: "query5",
        route: "admin",
        time: 5435
    },
]
```

to become this:

```
const array = [
                {
                    route: "home",
                    calls: [
                        {
                            query: "query1",
                            time: 1234
                        },
                        {
                            query: "query3",
                            time: 1200
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    route: "dashboard",
                    calls: [
                        {
                            query: "query2",
                            time: 4324
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    route: "admin",
                    calls: [
                        {
                            query: "query4",
                            time: 3333
                        },
                        {
                            query: "query5",
                            time: 5435
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` method and group the `array` with `key` equal to `route` property, and then use `Object.values` to get the values of the object.

```js
const array = [
    {
        query: "query1",
        route: "home",
        time: 1234
    },
    {
        query: "query2",
        route: "dashboard",
        time: 4324
    },
    {
        query: "query3",
        route: "home",
        time: 1200
    },
    {
        query: "query4",
        route: "admin",
        time: 3333
    },
    {
        query: "query5",
        route: "admin",
        time: 5435
    },
]

const result = Object.values(array.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.route] ? acc[item.route].cells.push({query: item.query, time: item.time}) : (acc[item.route] = {route: item.route, cells: [{query: item.query, time: item.time}]})
  return acc
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Map` to key the target objects by route, initially with empty `call` arrays. Then populate those `call` arrays and finally extract the values from the Map into the result array:

```js
const array = [{query: "query1",route: "home",time: 1234},{query: "query2",route: "dashboard",time: 4324},{query: "query3",route: "home",time: 1200},{query: "query4",route: "admin",time: 3333},{query: "query5",route: "admin",time: 5435},]

const map = new Map(array.map(({route}) => [route, { route, calls: [] }]));
for (const {route, ...rest} of array) map.get(route).calls.push(rest);
const result = [...map.values()];

console.log(result);
```